# Umbraco URLs disappeared

Tags: umbraco

I have about 50 pages in my Umbraco site and for some reason all of the URLs went from being based on the site structure to either just # or just the id of the page, like /1083

What would have caused that to happen and how can I fix it now?

Also, it would be nice to understand how these URLs get created if there is some method somewhere that manages it or they are in the database somewhere.

Comment: have you tried deleting the config.xml file and doing a re-publish of all the pages?

Comment: I have not. Where is that file?

Comment: I deleted the App_Data/umbraco.config file and then went into the admin and republished the whole site, and now it is fixed. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the App_Data/umbraco.config file and then go into the admin and republished the whole site.

Thanks @Pauli